# Xubuntu: A bootable windows usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, xubuntu

Over the past week or so, I've been trying to create a bootable USB on Xubuntu for Windows. It seems like everything has more or less been unsuccessful, with varying degrees of success.

Using the `dd` command doesn't make the .ISO file bootable on the usb, and UNetBootin isn't able to create windows bootable USBs. I've tried to run Wine to run Rufus, a program that creates bootable USBs on Windows, but it was unable to find my USB while it was mounted. I've tried CrossOver to install a multitude of ISO burning programs, but none have worked so far. I'm at the end of my rope,  and I'm wondering if there's anything else I should be doing or something I may have missed.

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: The Windows images boot just fine with UEFI, the problem is to boot in legacy mode.  I recommend Cornelius' answer (in the Q&A karel linked to) understand and configure a bootloader for MBR on the USB storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `dd` and the USB device is not booting, it means that the .iso file is not a hybrid file.  You have to convert it to a hybrid .iso before you create your bootable USB device with `dd`.  I haven't used this method for creating Windows bootable USB's yet but it works with all Linux isos I've tried so far.

1. Make sure the iso you've downloaded is ok using a checksum file.
2. Install **syslinux-utils** on your system by typing `sudo apt-get install syslinux-utils`.
3. If you want to keep the original iso intact, make a copy and process the copy by typing `isohybrid /path_to_copy.iso`.
4. After that, the copy's checksum test will fail and this is the sign that **isohybrid** has altered it so that it can create bootable USB devices too.
5. Type `dd if=altered.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M` (where X is your USB device letter).

You should be able to boot your system with your USB device after this.  I'll be waiting to see if this works with Windows isos too.